# Get the html element form $scope, that ng-repeat created from $scope?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Is it possible to get the html element (for styling) from the $scope object?

I'm using an `ng-repeat` on a `$scope.array` and I know that `$scope.array[0]` *corresponds* to the first element in the  HTML created by `ng-repeat`, so is it possible to get that ***HTML element itself*** through `$scope` in my javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach a controller to each element and inject $element to get access to each element that way. So it would look something like:

HTML:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-controller="itemController"></li>
```

Javascript:

```
module.controller('itemController', ['$scope', '$element', function($scope, $element) {
    // Use $element here
}]);
```

However, if you just want to change the styling of each element, you should consider using ng-class on each item, and then specifying the class with the $scope of each item.

If you want to do DOM manipulation, it's recommended that you do this within a directive.